# ¿Cómo puedo integrar esta validación para acceder al OWA de Office 365 o portal.office.com?

Tags: directorioactivo, office365, smartcard, adfs

`ADFS` se integra con `Office 365` y requiere poner `Usuario` y `Contraseña` del `Directorio Activo`.

¿Cómo configuro el `ADFS` para que trabaje con Tarjetas Inteligentes de la organización?.

Cada vez que trato acceder alguna aplicación en `Office 365` requiere credenciales y las mismas están guardadas en el `SmartCard` y aun así colocamos la `SmartCard` y no funciona.

Ya exporte el certificado de la `SmartCard` en `Directorio Activo` y aún así no funciona.

Comment: aquí hay un video que quizá te pueda ayudar https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Microsoft-Developer-Mexico/Office-365-para-desarrolladores [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cSF5N.jpg)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cSF5N.jpg)

Comment: Aqui hablan de ello y como configurarlo
[adfs para office 365 parte 1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2014/04/28/how-to-install-adfs-2012-r2-for-office-365.aspx) En el articulo tienes enlace a la parte 2 y 3 Aver si te soluciona tu problema para el login por OWA es http://outlook.com/dominio.com

Comment: por curiosidad, te refieres a estas: https://www.amazon.com/SainSmart-Generic-Contactless-125kHz-Proximity/dp/B00GXV4IGC/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1473900138&sr=8-6&keywords=smart+card y al lector: https://www.amazon.com/Card-Reader-125K-EM4100-TK4100/dp/B018C8C162/ref=pd_sim_60_2?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=ZCAAEWVYP2MFJ4038GZH ?

Comment: o te refieres a este par: https://www.amazon.com/PIVKey-C910-PKI-Smart-Card/dp/B00SJV2CNK/ref=pd_sim_147_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=7JH91SXA2BAMRD678A6H y https://www.amazon.com/Rocketek-RT-SCR1-Military-Compatible-Windows/dp/B00PY0CNYM/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1473900138&sr=8-5&keywords=smart+card ?

Answer (score 0):

Realizando una búsqueda rápida encontré un [artículo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-fs/operations/configure-additional-authentication-methods-for-ad-fs) en inglés que aplica para Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2012 R2. Este artículo indica lo siguiente (mas abajo está la traducción):

> In order to enable multi-factor authentication (MFA), you must select at least one additional authentication method. By default, in Active Directory Federation Services (AD FS) in Windows Server 2012 R2, you can select Certificate Authentication (in other words, smart card-based authentication) as an additional authentication method.
>
> > Note
> >
> > If you select Certificate Authentication, ensure that the smart card certificates have been provisioned securely and have pin requirements.

A continuación un borrador de traducción (énfasis mío).

Con la finalidad de habilitar la autenticación de múltiples factores, deberás seleccionar al menos un método de autenticación. De forma predeterminada, en los servicios federados del Directorio Activo (AD FS por sus siglas en inglés) en Windows Server 2012 R2, puedes seleccionar la Autenticación de Certificados ( en otras palabras, autenticación basada en tarjetas inteligentes) como un método adicional de autenticación.

Nota:

Si seleccionas la Autenticación de Certificados, **asegura que los certificados de tarjeta inteligente han sido provistos de forma segura y tiene requerimientos de número de identificación personal** (PIN por sus siglas en inglés).

Answer (score 0):

Para habilitar la autenticación mediante tarjetas inteligentes en ADFS para Office 365, necesitarás seguir varios pasos:

1. Configura tu tarjeta inteligente: Asegúrate de que la tarjeta inteligente esté configurada correctamente. Para ello, verifica que el Controlador de Tarjeta Inteligente y la Herramienta de Registro de Certificados estén instalados.
2. Configura el Directorio Activo: Asegúrate de que la Tarjeta Inteligente esté asociada con la cuenta de usuario en el Directorio Activo. Para ello, abre la Consola de Administración de Certificados y verifica que el certificado de la tarjeta inteligente esté instalado en el almacén de certificados de usuario.
3. Configura el ADFS: Debes configurar ADFS para que use la autenticación basada en certificados. Deberás configurar la directiva de autenticación de ADFS para incluir el método de autenticación basado en certificados. Configura la directiva en el servidor de ADFS mediante la creación o la edición de una directiva que permita la autenticación mediante certificados de cliente. Además, deberás especificar que ADFS ahora admite la autenticación basada en certificados en el registro de servicios de Office 365.
4. Configuración de Office 365: Configura Office 365 para que use la autenticación basada en certificados. Selecciona la opción de autenticación basada en certificados del Centro de administración de Office 365.

Una vez que haya realizado todos los pasos anteriores, deberías ser capaz de acceder a las aplicaciones en Office 365 utilizando la autenticación basada en tarjetas inteligentes. Si después de haber realizado todos estos pasos aún no puedes acceder, es posible que debas considerar la ayuda de un especialista en IT para llevar a cabo una solución de problemas más detallada.